# Regular Expression validation not working for Chinese culture in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I have a regular expression validator with client-side validation disabled in an ASP.Net page.  The regular expression being used for this validator is as below and it is validating input into a `Product Description` multi-line text box.

```
 Expression="^[\\p .,;'\-(0-9)\(\)\[\]]+$"
```

The culture for this ASP.Net app is Chinese as specified in web config.

```
<globalization uiCulture="zh" culture="zh-CHT" />
```

The following input into `Product Description` text box in same ASP.Net page is always failing. I am trying to match any one of these: chinese langauge character or period or comma or semi-colon or single quote or digits or round/square brackets.

**Question**: What is in the regular expression that is causing this input text to fail and how can I change it to satisfy the matching requirements?

`（1）降低庫存過程 （2）增加了吞吐量（1）降低庫存過程 （2）增加了吞吐量（1）降低庫存過程 （2）增加了吞吐量（1）降低庫存過程 （2）增加了吞吐量`

Comment: For a client-side validation, you need a JS-compatible regex. It doesn't support Unicode category classes like `\p{L}`. For a server-side validation. I think you could use `Expression=@"^[\p{L}\p{N}\s.,;'\-()\[\]]+$"`.

Comment: I have disabled client-side validation, so only server-side validation is done.

Comment: I have not tested my above regex, just trying to show that \p itself migt not be sufficient and it is safer to use a verbatim string literal. I also fixed a couple of issues.

Comment: Ok. I will check if your expression works. Thanks.

Comment: Just checked at regexstorm.net: `^[\p{L}\p{N}\s.,;（）'\-()\[\]]+$` works. The full-width parentheses prevented a match with my above suggestion. You need to also define any other full- or/and half-width punctuation. What about `^[\p{L}\p{N}\s\p{P}]+$`?.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much, Your expression works perfectly in my ASP.Net page with client-side validation disabled for non-English languages. This should work with English characters also? Also, please post this as an answer.

Comment: Yes it works with English characters also according to regexstorm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85231/discussion-between-stribizhev-and-sunil).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET regex, the one that works on server side, you can make use of [Unicode categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories).

```
^[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\s\p{P}]+$
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BM%7D%5Cp%7BN%7D%5Cs%5Cp%7BP%7D%5D%2B%24&i=%EF%BC%881%EF%BC%89%E9%99%8D%E4%BD%8E%E5%BA%AB%E5%AD%98%E9%81%8E%E7%A8%8B%0D%0A%EF%BC%882%EF%BC%89%E5%A2%9E%E5%8A%A0%E4%BA%86%E5%90%9E%E5%90%90%E9%87%8F%EF%BC%881%EF%BC%89%E9%99%8D%E4%BD%8E%E5%BA%AB%E5%AD%98%E9%81%8E%E7%A8%8B%0D%0A%EF%BC%882%EF%BC%89%E5%A2%9E%E5%8A%A0%E4%BA%86%E5%90%9E%E5%90%90%E9%87%8F%EF%BC%881%EF%BC%89%E9%99%8D%E4%BD%8E%E5%BA%AB%E5%AD%98%E9%81%8E%E7%A8%8B%0D%0A%EF%BC%882%EF%BC%89%E5%A2%9E%E5%8A%A0%E4%BA%86%E5%90%9E%E5%90%90%E9%87%8F%EF%BC%881%EF%BC%89%E9%99%8D%E4%BD%8E%E5%BA%AB%E5%AD%98%E9%81%8E%E7%A8%8B%0D%0A%EF%BC%882%EF%BC%89%E5%A2%9E%E5%8A%A0%E4%BA%86%E5%90%9E%E5%90%90%E9%87%8F)

So, the character class matches:

- `\p{L}` - Unicode letters
- `\p{M}` - diacritic marks
- `\p{N}` - numbers
- `\s` - whitespace
- `\p{P}` - punctuation.

Note these Unicode categories won't work on client-side where your Englsh UI culture validation takes place. You can use your fixed expression there:

```
^[a-zA-Z .,;'\-0-9()\[\]]+$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wW6cG2/1)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.